# The events don't appear on the fullcalendar in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar

I have a problem displaying the events in my fullcalendar. The data comes from the backend in the right format `title : "", start: "" and end: ""` and when I manually add some mock data in the `events` property inside `calendarOptions` it displays, but when I say `events: "this.listOfEvents"` -> the list of ojects that comes from by backend it does not appear. Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions" :events="calendarOptions.events" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
  },
  computed: mapGetters(["listOfEvents"]),
  data: () => ({
   // events: [],
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loggedUser")),
    startDateTime: moment()
      .clone()
      .format("D-M-YYYY h:mm:ss"),
    endDateTime: moment()
      .clone()
      .format("D-M-YYYY h:mm:ss"),
      calendarOptions: {
      events: "this.listOfEvents",  //this is where I am trying to bind it
    // events: [
    //   {
    //     title: "dsegr",
    //     start: "2020-11-14 10:00:00.0"  //if I manually do this with the data that comes from my 
                                                server it works
    //   }
    // ],
    },

  }),
  methods: {
    getEventByUserAndDate() {
      store.dispatch("getEventByUserAndDate", {
        userId: this.user.id,
        start: this.startDateTime,
        end: this.endDateTime,
      })
      this.events = this.listOfEvents;  
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getEventByUserAndDate();
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Because you put `"this.listOfEvents"` inside quote marks, JavaScript is treating it as a string (i.e. a simple piece of text), not a variable name. try `events: this.listOfEvents` instead.

Comment: P.S. I think `:events="calendarOptions.events"` in your template declaration will be ignored. `events` is already specified through the options, and you're already loading the options via `:options="calendarOptions"`...so it really makes no sense to do it again.

Comment: It doesn't work with the `events: this.listOfEvents` ..

Comment: Any errors in the console? Also, does this run after the list is passed to fullCalendar? Have you tried to debug that? "Doesn't work" isn't a very informative description

Comment: The whole thing blows up with errors like: `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'listOfEvents' of undefined"` , `9 [Vue warn]: Property or method "calendarOptions" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`, `Error in mounted hook: "Error: viewType "" is not available. Please make sure you've loaded all neccessary plugins"`, `Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"`. I've removed the events from my template and changed the events calendarOptions to this : `events: this.listOfEvents`. The res of the code is the same

Comment: `'listOfEvents' of undefined"` suggests that `this` is undefined in the context you're using it. I don't know vueJS very well, so I can't tell you exactly why that is, but it seems like you've got the scope wrong somewhere along the path.